# Disable soft keyboard completely for the whole cordova+crosswalk application for android

Tags: android, cordova, webview, android-softkeyboard, crosswalk

I want to disable the soft keyboard completely for an android cordova + crosswalk application, I have a manual keyboard which is rather different than the soft one, and in any case I cannot use the soft keyboard. Modifying the AndroidManifest.xml file to change android:windowSoftInputMode:stateAlwaysHidden does not help,  if the text box gains focus again, the keyboard pops up. How do I do this is cordova application where I am using crosswalk webview and not the native one?

Comment: You found any solution for this?